# How to find missing values positions in python?

Tags: python, pandas

If we want to find missing values positions in a vector, we can use **which** and **is.na** functions in R.

```
a=c(1,2,3,NA,5,6,NA)
positions=which(is.na(a))
```

How can we find missing values positions in python?

```
a=[1,2,3,np.nan,5,6,np.nan]
positions=pd.isnull(a)
```

Here I can get true or false. But I want to find missing values positions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.nonzero`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html):

```
In [307]:

a=[1,2,3,np.nan,5,6,np.nan]
np.nonzero(pd.isnull(a))
Out[307]:
(array([3, 6], dtype=int64),)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use enumerate and test each element of your list whith the numpy method : isnan()

```
indexes = [index for index,element in enumerate(a) if np.isnan(element)]
```

Answer (score 1):

when using

```
pd.isnull(a)
```

you get true as output when the value at that cell is missing,
you get false as output if the cell you are referring to has a certain value, and no missing value, here in this url you can find different ways to detect missing values
https://medium.com/@kanchanardj/jargon-in-python-used-in-data-science-to-laymans-language-part-two-98787cce0928

Answer (score 1):

If you have a pandas.Dataframe you can use this approach

```
df.loc[df['Feature'].isnull()]
```

It will return the lines of the specific column on thedataframe where Nan values are present.